# Indexes in INSERT SELECT query in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have a mysql query:

```
insert into `my_table`
select *
from (
    select 1 as id, 2 as b, 3 as c from dual 
    union all
    select 1, 5, 6 from dual 
    union all
    select 1, 8, 9 from dual
    ) as t
where not exists (
        select id
        from `my_table`
        where id = 1;
    )
```

I want to insert a bunch of rows corresponding to an id atomically if it has not been already inserted in the table. However this query comes in the slow logs of mysql, so I am wondering how sql handles indexes during this lock queries?

Is there a way to improve this query performance?

Comment: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,69223,69223 @GurwinderSingh

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I have noticed the "from dual" too, actualy it works :-) I've just tested with MySQL 5.7 at Ubuntu, both `select 1 from dual` and `select 1` works :-)

Comment: @JamesZ Can u help here?

Comment: @ArijitBasu I don't really understand your query -- you're inserting 3 rows that have nothing to do with {id} into the table, if {id} row doesn't exist. Sounds like checking the existence first would be better, or having index on id, if it doesn't exist already -- but I just came here to remove the SQL Server tag.

Comment: @JamesZ I have updated the query, my requirement is, I have to insert the  3 rows if id=1 is not already inserted into the table